# Return data from different database and output in form

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

I have an app in PHP/ SQL Server connected to database A. In a form, i want to populate a dropdown list with data from database B (same server).

What i made:

1. In config.php file i typed:

   ```
   try {
   $handler = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=server1;Database=attstocuri;ConnectionPooling=0", "sa", "");
   $handler -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   } catch (Exception $ex) {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
   die();
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   try {
   $handler2 = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=server1;Database=Legend;ConnectionPooling=0", "sa", "");
   $handler2 -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   } catch (Exception $ex) {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
   die();
   }
   ```
2. In index.php file (where is located the form):

   ```
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <select name="customerid">

   <?php
   $stmt2 = $handler2 -> query ('SELECT customer.id, customer.name from Legend.dbo.Customer');
   while ($row = $stmt2 ->fetch()){
   echo "<option value='".$row["customer.id"]."'>".$row["customer.name"]."</option>";
   }
   ?>
   </select>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productcode" placeholder="Cod articol" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['productcode'];} ?>"></input><br/>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" placeholder="Cantitate fara stoc" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['quantity'];} ?>"></input><br/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
   </form>
   ```

The **select** should return the info from the second database, but it's not showing anything ... what am i doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see the error log ?

Comment: @SaadSuri Where ? I don't have any error, just an empty drop down list ...
http://imgur.com/4vhBgEp

Comment: better do the query before you start your html code. Should the query fail and print an error message, you prob. won't see it as it inside a <select>tag and you need to view in the page source or errorlog for clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I'm no PHP dev but you can potentially resolve this from a DB perspective. If both databases are in the same SQL server instance then simply create a view in the App DB refrencing the drop down options you want to use and use this the same in your app as any other table or view.

In attstocuri run

```
CREATE VIEW MyDropDown AS 
SELECT 
customer.id
, customer.name 
FROM Legend.dbo.Customer
GO
```

Then you can reference it from the same connection. You will need to ensure the permissions for the user the app connects to attstocuri with have permission on the Customer table in Legend though.

If the databases were not on the same server or the other database was not SQL server then you could still use this method after setting up a linked server.